# Git+Gerrit: Merge two dependent branches with tree changes

Tags: git, version-control, merge, gerrit

I have `master` and two branches: `branch-a` and `branch-b`. First contains some code changes, but remains on unchanged (old) files and folder structure. Second does not introduce any changes to code, but has a completely new file and folder structure.

What I did, was:

1. I did some changes to `branch-a` and commited them. Then I pushed them to Gerrit, but change wasn't reviewed yet, because it is unfinished.
2. Then I did a serious structure change. But I mistakenly did it before switching to a new branch. Committing to `branch-a` seemed wrong to me. I wasn't able to checkout `master`, because git warned me about possible changes being overwritten and asked to either commit or stash.
3. So, I created a new `branch-b`, commited all changes to it and pushed it to Gerrit. It was reviewed, but is now in `Submitted, Merge Pending` state, because it depends on `branch-a`, not reviewed yet.

How should I proceed now? Is there any way (in this scenario) to have changes from `branch-a` merged to `master` and remain on folder structure introduced with `branch-b`?

I can't review and submit changes from `branch-a`, because works over it hasn't been finished yet. (I think) I can't merge it to master on local side, because it has significant tree structure changes (old folder structure) and would overwrite everything, that was done later, with `branch-b`. (I think) I can't merge `branch-a` (code changes) to `master` and then merge `branch-b` (structure change) over it, cause I would end up with new files and folder structure, but old code (`branch-b` would overwrite `branch-a`).

What should I do now? How to clean this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new branch `branch-c` reset it by `git reset --hard origin/master` cherry-pick the commit from local `branch-b` push it to review and it will be merged without dependecies. Then abandon the change coming from  `branch-b`.

Comment: Either I'm missing something, or that solves only half of the problem. If I follow you, I'll have reviewed and merged structure change (`branch-c` cherry-piked from `branch-b`). But when I finally apply `branch-a` over it, it will either not be merged (due to significant files and folders location change) or, it will revert files structure back to old one.

Comment: when the commit submitted on `branch-c`, rebase `branch-a` with origin/master `git rebase -p origin/master` solve the conflict and push the new patchset to remote review branch